# Flutter Json Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter

Class Category
Error: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

```
  class Category {
  int id;
  String categoryName;
  String seoUrl;


  Category(this.id,this.categoryName,this.seoUrl);

  Category.fromJson(Map json){
    id = json["id"];
    categoryName = json["categoryName"];
    seoUrl = json["seoUrl"];
  }

  Map toJson(){
    return {
      "id": id,
      "categoryName": categoryName,
      "seoUrl": seoUrl
    };
  }
}
```

Class Main Screen

Error: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http_demo/data/api/category_api.dart';
import 'package:http_demo/models/category.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MainScreenState();
  }
}

class MainScreenState extends State {
  List<Category> categories = List<Category>();
  List<Widget> categoryWidgets = List<Widget>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCategoriesFromApi();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Alışveriş Sistemi",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: categoryWidgets,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void getCategoriesFromApi() {
    CategoryApi.getCategories().then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        //categories = list.map((category) => Category.fromJson(category)).toList();
        this.categories = List<Category>.from(list.map((model)=> Category.fromJson(model)));
        getCategoryWidgets();
      });
    });
  }

  List<Widget> getCategoryWidgets() {
    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
      categoryWidgets.add(getCategoryWidget(categories[i]));
    }
    return categoryWidgets;
  }

  Widget getCategoryWidget(Category category) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: null,
      child: Text(
        category.categoryName,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`Error: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`
Error: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'
Error: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'
Error: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'
Error: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the response after convert JSON.

```
void getCategoriesFromApi() {
  CategoryApi.getCategories().then((response) {
    setState(() {
      var list = json.decode(response.body);
      //categories = list.map((category) => Category.fromJson(category)).toList();
      if (list is List) {
        this.categories = list.map((e) => Category.fromJson(e)).toList();
        getCategoryWidgets();
      } else {
        print('response is not list');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: can you share the response.body ?

Comment: I got the text "response is not list"                                                                               
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
class CategoryApi{
  static Future getCategories(){
    return http.get("http://10.0.2.2:3000/category");
  }
}

Comment: Yes. you can check the response.  print(response.body);

Comment: class Category {
  int id;
  String categoryName;
  String seoUrl;


  Category(this.id,this.categoryName,this.seoUrl);

  Category.fromJson(Map json){
    id = json["id"];
    categoryName = json["categoryName"];
    seoUrl = json["seoUrl"];
  }

  Map toJson(){
    return {
      "id": id,
      "categoryName": categoryName,
      "seoUrl": seoUrl
    };
  }
}

Comment: I'm using bluestack.

Comment: I mean you need to check server response.

Comment: print(response.body); ---> {}         //I got this result

Comment: received empty Map?

Comment: please don't be sorry. I'm stupid and inexperienced. http://10.0.2.2:3000/categories "I should have written http://10.0.2.2:3000/category" :(. Thank you for your help. I solved it thanks to you. I'm very novice: / (my English is bad)